# Java - Right Clicking JTabbledPane Tab

Tags: java, swing, popup, popupwindow, jtabbedpane

I have it working, however the popup menu appears when you right click anywhere inside the tab. I only would like it to appear when you right click the top of the tab (the name). I cannot figure out how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you implemented it, can you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) ?

Comment: @SérgioMichels I just use a `MouseAdapter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding your popup to the custom component demonstrated in [`TabComponentsDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html#eg).

Comment: @JonMannerberg see the "Tabs With Custom Components". In the example exists a button to close the tab, but i think you can adjust to your needs.