# How to add close button in BasicTabbedPaneUI?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtabbedpane

I'm trying to build a JTabbedPane using BasicTabbedPaneUI. I found an example of it which doesn't works perfectly. But it doesn't have a close button so that i can close the current tab.

How can i add a close button in it?

Here is my code:

```
public class TabbedPane extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static final JButton backButton = new JButton();

public TabbedPane() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JTabbedPane tb = new JTabbedPane();
    tb.setUI(new CustomTabbedPaneUI());
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    tb.add("Tab1", pane);
    MyCloseButton button = new MyCloseButton();
    jp.add(new JLayer<JTabbedPane>(tb));
    jp.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("add tab") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tb.addTab("test", new JPanel());
        }
    }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    jp.add(tb, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(new TabbedPane());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

and

```
public class CustomTabbedPaneUI extends BasicTabbedPaneUI {

private Color selectColor;
private Color deSelectColor;
private int inclTab = 4;
private int anchoFocoV = inclTab;
private int anchoFocoH = 4;
private int anchoCarpetas = 18;
private Polygon shape;

public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
    return new CustomTabbedPaneUI();
}

@Override
protected void installDefaults() {
    super.installDefaults();
    selectColor = new Color(250, 192, 192);
    deSelectColor = new Color(197, 193, 168);
    tabAreaInsets.right = anchoCarpetas;
}

@Override
protected void paintTabArea(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int selectedIndex) {
    if (runCount > 1) {
        int lines[] = new int[runCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < runCount; i++) {
            lines[i] = rects[tabRuns[i]].y + (tabPlacement == TOP ? maxTabHeight : 0);
        }
        Arrays.sort(lines);
        if (tabPlacement == TOP) {
            int fila = runCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++, fila--) {
                Polygon carp = new Polygon();
                carp.addPoint(0, lines[i]);
                carp.addPoint(tabPane.getWidth() - 2 * fila - 2, lines[i]);
                carp.addPoint(tabPane.getWidth() - 2 * fila, lines[i] + 3);
                if (i < lines.length - 2) {
                    carp.addPoint(tabPane.getWidth() - 2 * fila, lines[i + 1]);
                    carp.addPoint(0, lines[i + 1]);
                } else {
                    carp.addPoint(tabPane.getWidth() - 2 * fila, lines[i] + rects[selectedIndex].height);
                    carp.addPoint(0, lines[i] + rects[selectedIndex].height);
                }
                carp.addPoint(0, lines[i]);
                g.setColor(hazAlfa(fila));
                g.fillPolygon(carp);
                g.setColor(darkShadow.darker());
                g.drawPolygon(carp);
            }
        } else {
            int fila = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++, fila++) {
                Polygon carp = new Polygon();
                carp.addPoint(0, lines[i]);
                carp.addPoint(tabPane.getWidth() - 2 * fila - 1, lines[i]);
                carp.addPoint(tabPane.getWidth() - 2 * fila - 1, lines[i + 1] - 3);
                carp.addPoint(tabPane.getWidth() - 2 * fila - 3, lines[i + 1]);
                carp.addPoint(0, lines[i + 1]);
                carp.addPoint(0, lines[i]);
                g.setColor(hazAlfa(fila + 2));
                g.fillPolygon(carp);
                g.setColor(darkShadow.darker());
                g.drawPolygon(carp);
            }
        }
    }
    super.paintTabArea(g, tabPlacement,selectedIndex);
}

@Override
protected void paintTabBackground(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int tabIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean isSelected) {
    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    GradientPaint gradientShadow;
    int xp[] = null; // Para la forma
    int yp[] = null;
    switch (tabPlacement) {
        case LEFT:
            xp = new int[]{x, x, x + w, x + w, x};
            yp = new int[]{y, y + h - 3, y + h - 3, y, y};
            gradientShadow = new GradientPaint(x, y, new Color(100, 100, 255), x, y + h, Color.ORANGE);
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            xp = new int[]{x, x, x + w - 2, x + w - 2, x};
            yp = new int[]{y, y + h - 3, y + h - 3, y, y};
            gradientShadow = new GradientPaint(x, y, new Color(100, 100, 255), x, y + h, new Color(153, 186, 243));
            break;
        case BOTTOM:
            xp = new int[]{x, x, x + 3, x + w - inclTab - 6, x + w - inclTab - 2, x + w - inclTab, x + w - 3, x};
            yp = new int[]{y, y + h - 3, y + h, y + h, y + h - 1, y + h - 3, y, y};
            gradientShadow = new GradientPaint(x, y, new Color(100, 100, 255), x, y + h, Color.BLUE);
            break;
        case TOP:
        default:
            xp = new int[]{x, x, x + 3, x + w - inclTab - 6, x + w - inclTab - 2, x + w - inclTab, x + w - inclTab, x};
            yp = new int[]{y + h, y + 3, y, y, y + 1, y + 3, y + h, y + h};
            gradientShadow = new GradientPaint(0, 0, Color.ORANGE, 0, y + h / 2, new Color(240, 255, 210));
            break;
    }
    shape = new Polygon(xp, yp, xp.length);
    if (isSelected) {
        g2D.setColor(selectColor);
        g2D.setPaint(gradientShadow);
    } else {
        if (tabPane.isEnabled() && tabPane.isEnabledAt(tabIndex)) {
            g2D.setColor(deSelectColor);
            GradientPaint gradientShadowTmp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, new Color(255, 255, 200), 0, y + h / 2, new Color(240, 255, 210));
            g2D.setPaint(gradientShadowTmp);
        } else {
            GradientPaint gradientShadowTmp = new GradientPaint(0, 0, new Color(240, 255, 210), 0, y + 15 + h / 2, new Color(204, 204, 204));
            g2D.setPaint(gradientShadowTmp);
        }
    }
    g2D.fill(shape);
    if (runCount > 1) {
        g2D.setColor(hazAlfa(getRunForTab(tabPane.getTabCount(), tabIndex) - 1));
        g2D.fill(shape);
    }
    g2D.fill(shape);
}

@Override
protected void paintText(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, Font font, FontMetrics metrics, int tabIndex, String title, Rectangle textRect, boolean isSelected) {
    super.paintText(g, tabPlacement, font, metrics, tabIndex, title, textRect, isSelected);
    g.setFont(font);
    View v = getTextViewForTab(tabIndex);
    if (v != null) {
        // html
        v.paint(g, textRect);
    } else {
        // plain text
        int mnemIndex = tabPane.getDisplayedMnemonicIndexAt(tabIndex);
        if (tabPane.isEnabled() && tabPane.isEnabledAt(tabIndex)) {
            MyCloseButton button = new MyCloseButton();
            g.setColor(tabPane.getForegroundAt(tabIndex));
            BasicGraphicsUtils.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(g, title, mnemIndex, textRect.x, textRect.y + metrics.getAscent());
        } else { // tab disabled
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            BasicGraphicsUtils.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(g, title, mnemIndex, textRect.x, textRect.y + metrics.getAscent());
            g.setColor(tabPane.getBackgroundAt(tabIndex).darker());
            BasicGraphicsUtils.drawStringUnderlineCharAt(g, title, mnemIndex, textRect.x - 1, textRect.y + metrics.getAscent() - 1);
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected int calculateTabWidth(int tabPlacement, int tabIndex, FontMetrics metrics) {
    return 20 + inclTab + super.calculateTabWidth(tabPlacement, tabIndex, metrics);
}

@Override
protected int calculateTabHeight(int tabPlacement, int tabIndex, int fontHeight) {
    if (tabPlacement == LEFT || tabPlacement == RIGHT) {
        return super.calculateTabHeight(tabPlacement, tabIndex, fontHeight);
    } else {
        return anchoFocoH + super.calculateTabHeight(tabPlacement, tabIndex, fontHeight);
    }
}

@Override
protected void paintTabBorder(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, int tabIndex, int x, int y, int w, int h, boolean isSelected) {
}

@Override
protected void paintFocusIndicator(Graphics g, int tabPlacement, Rectangle[] rects, int tabIndex, Rectangle iconRect, Rectangle textRect, boolean isSelected) {
    if (tabPane.hasFocus() && isSelected) {
        g.setColor(UIManager.getColor("ScrollBar.thumbShadow"));
        g.drawPolygon(shape);
    }
}

protected Color hazAlfa(int fila) {
    int alfa = 0;
    if (fila >= 0) {
        alfa = 50 + (fila > 7 ? 70 : 10 * fila);
    }
    return new Color(0, 0, 0, alfa);
}
}
```

Here is my Button class which i want to add in the code above

```
class MyCloseButton extends JButton{

public MyCloseButton() {
    super("X");       
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    setFocusPainted(false);
    setBorderPainted(false);
    setContentAreaFilled(false);
    setRolloverEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(16, 16);
}
}
```

Comment: Try the `TabComponentsDemo`, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9220941/230513).

Comment: Here is example --> CloseableTabbedPane 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/41158575/1521710